# Not able to send email via smtp.gmail.com on AWS EC2

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, smtp

I am not able to send an email via app using `smtp.gmail.com` on `aws es2` with route53, however It is working fine on my local system

I am using following configuration

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=xxxxxx@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=######
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
```

**Error Received**

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu
534-5.7.14 ee9D-Q4FF1Qf1C0brZ5yyBgjly-Dcd72KznHCmCiWukMqfhBZYF0hoXQaIYmvy-POsSpm
534-5.7.14 dz-R07OXf5mfyVmnCtydKpyoNNWYQOUTE7ZE4ecOjqrFL9cMf0rG6WhCjRP3IObV>
534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 j9sm2100533pfe.170 - gsmtp

at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
at org.ravi.aveefashion.service.EmailService.sendMail(EmailService.java:42)
at org.ravi.aveefashion.demo.RestServices.sendEmail(RestServices.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java
```

My `lesssecure` setting in gmail is on and IMAP assess is also enabled.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no problem in the code and there is no problem in AWS configuration. It was gmail which was blocking login attempt. So I have to do two things,

```
**1. turn on Allow less secure apps in settings

2. go to `https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue**
```